# Bootstrap aligning two columns side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the input field to the left as shown in the screen shot?

here is my code and I have tried but no luck...

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">  
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">C 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on it and figured out how to give you that layout, you were missing a container and some CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A 1</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 1</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">  
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
           </div>
       </div>

   </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 2</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div style='clear:both'></div>
         <div class="col-md-6">

       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">C 3</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
   margin-top: 20px;
}

input{
   margin: 5px;
}
```

Working Example: [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/WQKWLg/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would to

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">  
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">C 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">

 </div>
```